# sed command: how to find and modify multiple patterns simultaneously?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix, sed

I have a problem I need to address with bash and particularly sed.
My data set is something like this:

```
James, L- PF 00
Jordan, M- PF 23
Bird, L- C 33
```

I need to end up with something like this:

```
uniform number for L. James: 00
uniform number for M. Jordan: 23
```

with a single sed command.

My initial tries were something like this:

```
sed -r 's/(.*), ([[:upper:]])- ([0-9]+)/uniform number for \2. \1: \3/' filename
```

but I can't seem to get any matches for the number part. I managed to get the first name letter and the last name in an earlier version, but nothing combined with the number...

Any help? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using `|` in the regular expression? That's for alternative patterns to match.

Comment: yeah not quite sure, got the advice from somewhere online.
either way, didn't work without it

Comment: That advice was obviously for a different problem.

Comment: So, you just missed to match anything between `-` and the number? `sed -r 's/(.*), ([[:upper:]])-.* ([0-9]+)/uniform number for \2. \1: \3/'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you missed `.*` to match any text between `-` and the number:

```sh
sed -r 's/(.*), ([[:upper:]])-.* ([0-9]+)/uniform number for \2. \1: \3/' nba_roster.txt
#                             ^^
```

You can also use

```sh
sed -E 's/^([^,]+), ([[:upper:]])[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*/uniform number for \2. \1: \3/' nba_roster.txt
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/2FB9Gy):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='Sims, J- PF 45
Samanic, L- PF 91
Noel, N- C 3'
sed -E 's/^([^,]+), ([[:upper:]])[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*/uniform number for \2. \1: \3/' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
uniform number for J. Sims: 45
uniform number for L. Samanic: 91
uniform number for N. Noel: 3
```

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `([^,]+)` - Group 1 (`\1`): any one or more chars other than a comma
- `,`  - a comma and space
- `([[:upper:]])` - Group 2 (`\2`): an uppercase letter
- `[^0-9]*` - zero or more non-digit chars
- `([0-9]+)` - Group 3 (`\3`): one or more digits
- `.*` - the rest of the string (if any).

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
sed 's/\([^,]*\), \([A-Z]\)[^0-9]*\(.*\)/uniform number for \2. \1: \3/' input_file
uniform number for J. Sims: 45
uniform number for L. Samanic: 91
uniform number for N. Noel: 3
```